# Moderators migrating questions without fixing MathJAX

Tags: discussion, migration, mathjax

A [question I've answered](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25755/burning-air-pressure-switch?answertab=votes#tab-top) has been migrated to Mechanics by Matt Young, PeterJ, nidhin and Nick Alexeev.

*Mechanics* doesn't support MathJAX so my answer is semi-banjaxed now.

Can the moderators please take this into consideration before migration? It's happened me before where an answer was migrated to Arduino.

Comment: Roger that. (On a different note: does Arduino.SE still not have MathJAX?)

Comment: @Nick I think the following list is up-to-date and looks like Arduino doesn't have it either: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607